# Svelte App can read firebase database, but not add

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, materialize, svelte-3

Hello stackoverflow community.
I am making a simple database application using Svelte, Materialize CSS, and firebase.
I am able to read from the firebase database, so I know it is not a credentials problem, however upon using the "addLink" function below, the database does not update. The alerts show the date, and newLink string correctly as well. Code in context is below as well.

```
function addLink() {
    alert(date.getTime());
    db.collection("links").add({ link: newLink, id: date.getTime() });
  }
```

```
<script>
  import GetForm from "../layout/GetForm.svelte";
  import TranslateButton from "../layout/TranslateButton.svelte";
  import { db } from "../firebase.js";

  let arrList = [];
  let newLink = "";
  let date = new Date();

  db.collection("links")
    .orderBy("id", "asc")
    .onSnapshot(snapData => {
      arrList = snapData.docs;
    });

  function addLink() {
    alert(date.getTime());
    db.collection("links").add({ link: newLink, id: date.getTime() });
  }
</script>

<div class="container right-align" style="margin-top: 30px;">
  <TranslateButton />
</div>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 150px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="center-align">
      <div class="row">
        <form class="col s12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s10">
              <textarea
                id="textarea1"
                class="materialize-textarea"
                bind:value={newLink} />
              <label for="textarea1">Put your URL here.</label>
            </div>
            <button
              class="btn waves-effect waves-light col s2"
              on:click={addLink}>
              Send
              <i class="material-icons right">arrow_forward</i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="center-align">
      <GetForm />
    </div>
  </div>

  <ul>
    {#each arrList as listItem}
      <li>{listItem.data().link}</li>
    {/each}
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the official documentation [Set a Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) indicates, you need to use the method `set()` to add documents to your collection. One example of an insert in the database is the following - the documentation is in Node.js, but I believe it should help you as a starting point.

```
let data = {
  link: 'Link you want',
  id: 'Id you want'
};

let setDoc = db.collection('link').doc('Id').set(data);
```

This is just a simple example of adding a document to a collection, but it should help you understading the logic for your.

Besides that, in the below articles, you should get more information on how to perform queries on Firestore.

- [Get started with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart)
- [Adding Data](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: In your second link it says that  `add()` is valid... thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

## Adding a new entry in Firestore DB

Which tutorial are you following for firebase? That's not how you add data to firebase. Replace `add()` with `set()`

### For Automatically generated ID

Pass your nothing as an argument to the `doc()`

```js
// For automatically generated id
db.collection('links')
  .doc()
  .set({ link: newLink })  
  .then(() => {  // fetch the doc again and show its data
    ref.get().then(doc => {
        console.log(doc.data())  // prints {link: newLink, id: 1321415}
    })
  })
```

### For using your own id

Pass your `id` as an argument to the `doc()`

```js
// Or you could set your own id, which is in your case,
// Pass your `id` as argument for `doc()`
db.collection("links")
  .doc(date.getTime())
  .set({
    link: newLink
  })
```

[Add data to Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Here is the timestamp of the tutorial in question: https://youtu.be/L39XLne7EU8?t=434

Comment: That was weird! Perhaps he was using old version. But it was `set()` as long as remember

Comment: In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data) it says that `add()` is valid... thank you though.

Comment: Yes, I read it too. "Behind the scenes, .`add(...)` and `.doc().set(...)` are completely equivalent, so you can use whichever is more convenient." Will check again and update

Comment: But did you check with `set()`?